# Make cell fill availble space with its text, but not add whitespaces

Tags: html, css

Conclusion: use JavaScript to calculate max-width of first cell.

Example:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden">Some text. It maybe very long and should be shortened if there is no more available width in table</td> 
        <td>This shall always be visible and should not have any space between this and the previous cell, but if the two cells are thinner than the table I want my white-spaces after the end of this cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I don't know is the width of cell2 or the width of the table

What I want to achieve is to have a max-width on the first cell, based on available space without using JavaScript. Not sure if it even is possible.

Example where the text is short:

```
|Some short text|Her comes a new text                |
```

Example where the text is too long:

```
|This is some text which might s|Her comes a new text|
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard to determine exactly what you want- [**perhaps something like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8S9L/2/)

HTML

```
<div>
   <span>Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.</span> 
   <span>here is some moreSomething quite long that should exceed the table cell.Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
span{
    padding 0 20;
    margin:0;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
span:first-child{
     white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
span:last-child{
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Sort of, but I want no whitespaces between the elements. Also everything should be on one line and the entire text in element 2 should be visible. (I assume that element 2 is thinner than the table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector `:first-child` to select the first `<td>` inside a table:

```
table td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wont work if the text in the cell is bigger than available space. It will only expand the table

Comment: Then add `word-wrap: break-word;` and `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: I already tried those. Since I use white-space:nowrap it still expands the table. Also if the text i short it will create whitespaces between the cells

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/SMvQP/)?

All I did was add a `max-width` to the cell that you want a max width on.

```
td:first-child {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I updated the post. Max-width does the trick, but I do not know how big the table well be, hence what the max-width attribute shall be

Comment: I don't think you will be able to specify a max width of a table cell without knowing what that max width would need to be...

Comment: Correct, thats why I had to find a different solution :) It looks like the best solution is to calculate the max-width from javascript

Comment: That's the route I would go down!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution without JavaScript is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:80%;">Some text. It maybe very long and should be shortened if there is no more available width in table</td> 
        <td>This shall always be visible and should not have any space between this and the previous cell, but if the two cells are thinner than the table I want my white-spaces after the end of this cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Apologies, if I do not understand what exactly you want!

Comment: Good suggestion, but I do not know the exact size relation between the cells